# Custom UIViewController modal transition from right like Flipboard

Tags: ios, segue, uistoryboardsegue, uiviewanimationtransition, flipboard

I need to make a custom modal transition segue on iPad to make that the destinationViewController appears from right, covering window half size and maintaining visible the initial View. More or less like the right panel in Flipboard App.

Any suggestions? Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can take a check [ViewDeck](https://github.com/Inferis/ViewDeck)